# AHK first character is repeated for hot strings

Tags: windows-10, autohotkey, hibernate

`::cl::call`

For this hotstring, after hibernation for `cl` gets `ccall` the first character is repeated in windows 10.

```
~^.::reload
```

I added this hotstring to reload.

AHK version: v1.1.30.03 - April 5, 2019

How to solve this bug without reloading?

---

Now on startup also this happens after some time!

Comment: I used hibernate trigger to press `^.`

Answer (score 1):

Try making it a multi-line routine and put a sleep statement before sending the replacement text (also, make sure to use a return statement)

Comment: Thats too failed

Answer (score 0):

try this, and read the documentation for help
https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm

```
:*:cl::call
```

Comment: `*` is just used when ending character not required. Here not the case